# Issue using optgroup in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 groups with conditions (Principal and Others).
And is not working because I'm doing a wrong sintaxis.

My table

```
|invoice_cia|
  |id| |name|
    1    ABC
    2    DEF
    3    FGH
    4    IJK
```

My controller:

```
def index
  @cias = invoice_cia.find(:all,:conditions=>['id IN (1,2)'])
  @cias2 = invoice_cia.find(:all,:conditions=>['id NOT IN (1,2)'])
end
```

My index view but is not working because I'm using it wrong:

```
<%= option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@cias.map{|t| t.name, t.id},@cias2.map{|t| t.name, t.id} )>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9mpBw/

Here is the log:

```
compile error
/home/master/proyects/test/app/views/invoice/index.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...ct(@cias.map{|t| t.name, t.id},@cias2.map{|t| t.name, t.id} ...
                          ^
/home/master/proyects/test/app/views/invoice/index.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...},@cias2.map{|t| t.name, t.id} )).to_s); @output_buffer.conc...
                           ^
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: `@cias.map{|t| t.name, t.id}` this raise error

Comment: if you post some questions this error case, please post errors trace.

Comment: Philidor can you check my demo? http://jsfiddle.net/9mpBw/ ...I want to do that but without using html tags just rails code.

Comment: do you try read [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select)?

Comment: Yes but I'm a little confused....http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56129/discussion-between-carlitos-morales-and-philidor-green).

Comment: OK I understood everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I had prepared an answer yesterday, but it seems Charlie Brown has already helped you solve the problem. I'll simply touch on the one issue he did not mention.*

The issue you were having is due to, as the error message indicates, improper syntax. Generally in Ruby it is acceptable to omit braces and brackets in situations where there is no ambiguity (meaning, where its obvious), however in all other cases, you must include them.

In your case, it appears you were attempting to return an array in your `map` block:

```
@cias.map{|t| t.name, t.id}
```

The compiler can't assume what you're attempting to do, so it complains. You must include the brackets, in this case:

```
@cias.map{|t| [t.name, t.id] } # note the array brackets []
```

Comment: Thank you for the help =) ..Paul can you help me with this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372162/how-can-sum-complete-string-with-number

Answer (score 1):

According with the page:

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select
```

Here is what you want in your view:

```
<% grouped_options = {
        '1.Principals' => options_for_select(@cias.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]}),
        '2.Others'       => options_for_select(@cias2.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]}) } %>

<%= select_tag "cia",grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options)  %>
```