# How can sum complete string with number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I save numbers before

Here is my table:

```
|products|
    int   varchar(10)
   |id|  |num_product| 
     1      0040

|customers|
   int   varchar(255)
   |id|    |name|     |state|
     1      ABC          0
     2      DEF          0
     3      GHI          0
     4      JKL          1
```

Here is the controller:

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @num= Product.first
  @other_value = Customer.count(:conditions=>['state=0'])
end
```

Here is my view:

```
<% (@num.num_product)+@other_value %>
```

But it returns `00403` instead of `0043`. I tried this but I'm getting `403` without `00`:

```
<% (@num.num_product.to_i)+@other_value.to_i %>
```

Also I tried this but is not the correct way:

```
<% "000"+(@num.num_product.to_i)+@other_value.to_i %>
```

Can somebody help me about this?

Comment: You asked me to take a look at this question, but Nicooga's answer appears perfectly good; what trouble are you having?

Comment: @other_value is a dynamic value and is not static value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you do:

```
"%04d" % (@num.num_product.to_i + 1)
```

Given `@num.num_product #=> "0040"` then:

```
"%04d" % ('0040'.to_i + 1)
=> "0041"
```

Comment: If I worried about fancyness then I'd store num_product as simply an integer and use a decorator to display it as formated by `"%04d"`.

Comment: What's the logic? 1 => 0001, 999 => 0999, 9999 => 9999, 12345 => 12345 (?).

Comment: If you don't stablish a limit of digits for the stored number then there can be no dynamic logic. Either way.. `increment_string_by '0001', 9999 # => "10000"`

Comment: Ruby (and most languages) disregards leading zeroes when printing. To print them you need to use a format string like `"%04d" % 92`, being `4` the max number of zeroes. numbers bigger than `10^4 - 1` don't get any leading zeroes.

Comment: nicooga cna you read my post again? I edited and added information

Comment: You can use the same code, just sum the arguments casted `to_i`

Comment: The problem is +1 is not an static value

Comment: @CarlitosMorales Where nicooga wrote ` + 1 `, just write `@other_value`. I'm assuming they did that simply as an example, but the principle is the same.